# Problems with flutter wireless debugging in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Update to flutter 3.16.9 today. vcode has the latest version of flutter installed. xcode settings have iPhone wireless connection settings.

When I click the debug button wirelessly in vscode, the screen stops on the splash page and I can't access the main page. But if I push the debug button by wire, everything works fine. I don't think I can connect to dart vm, can someone help me?

Strangely, if I run "flutter --run" in the terminal, the app works fine. But if I run it in the terminal, I can't hot-reload the modified code.

I restarted the Mac, reinstalled the flutter extensions, and turned off and on the developer settings on my iPhone.

I had an iPhone and a Mac on the same network, and I tried to connect using my iPhone's personal hotspot.

I've done all of the above, but my app is stuck on the splash page. Of course, I allowed the app to connect to the local network.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app on your phone before running a new build?

Comment: Yes I deleted the app every time and clicked the debugging button.